# Connect to Phabricator Conduit API with pure javascript

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest, phabricator

I'm try connect to Phabricator Conduit API with pure javascript, no succcess.

The code sample is:

```
var _TOKEN = (new Date().getTime() / 1000 + "");

var connect_params: ({
   "host": _PHAB,
   "user": _USER,
   "authToken": _TOKEN,
   "clientVersion": 1.0,
   "client": "phabricator-client",
   "authSignature": hash.sha1(_TOKEN + _CERT),
});

post("/api/conduit.connect", formData, requestCallback);

function post(requestPath, dataToSend, callback) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.open(requestType, phabricatorUrl + requestPath, true);

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
         callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText), parseInt(xhr.status));
   }
 }

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", parseInt(dataToSend));
xhr.send(dataToSend);
```

I get the result as json:

```
{"result":null,"error_code":"ERR-INVALID-CERTIFICATE","error_info":"Your authentication certificate for this server is invalid."}
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the Conduit `api.token` in your post to `/api/conduit.connect`.

You can create an API token from the Phabricator web interface at `Settings > Conduit API Tokens`